# Stack exchange trap, what do?

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

I have discusion with administration stack overflow, so what I can do with this?

> We are no longer accepting answers from this account.

And if I want escape this I must get more reputation, but how I can do this?
I can't comment beacuse I haven't enough reputation and I cant answer the question, where logic? Is best way delete account? usless rules, how I can get around this isue? Please maybe any one have another way?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why they are "baning" your answers? I trust Stack Exhange's moderators to carry out fair judgement, i am sure there is a valid reason for doing this.

Comment: They banning my answer beacuse I have low viewed question :)

Comment: `usless rules, how I can get around this isue?` Don't use this site? And no, you are not getting banned just because other people won't look at your questions.

Comment: [IT'S A TRAP!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F4qzPbcFiA). *Sorry, couldn't resist...*

Comment: How many deleted questions do you have? from what I can see on your profile, you are not in a GOOD standing, but I don't think a ban just because you have 5 questions with 0 and 1 question with 1 is the way the automated bans go... so you most definitely have deleted stuff

Comment: You were banned from answering because you left this disgusting insult of an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27904524/19679 , which was downvoted and removed. You then proceeded to spew obscenities at other members of the site, which led to your suspension. Finally, you created a new account so that you could continue to insult people: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33126252/19679 , which I destroyed yesterday.  We do expect members of this site to behave in a civil manner.

Comment: @Patrice It's an answer ban, not a question ban.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The moderators of stack exchange have undoubtedly made the right decision.
Read the rules in fully and try to improve your answers or not answer if your answer quality can be considered low.

The rules of this community are made for a reason and moderators are here to make sure everything goes right.
I don't know how you can regain the ability to post answers.

Links with info:

['Question' from moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

[Answer by same moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584)

[Help center about answer ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)

Comment: _"The moderators of stack exchange have undoubtedly made the right decision."_ The question and answer bans are _automatic_ and not actually done by mods. (Though they can be _influenced_ by mods if the mods delete downvoted posts from a user. A deleted post in general weighs in with the ban algorithm) The bans are based on how questions or answers by a user have been received. This is actually pointed out in some of the links you've posted.